# Error: value of type 'String' has no member 'hasSuffix' in Swift switch

Tags: switch-statement, swift3

I'm following tutorials from [Swift.org](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH2-ID1)

The below example of switch statement throws an error.

```
let vegetable = "red pepper"
switch vegetable {
case "celery":
    print("Add some raisins and make ants on a log.")
case "cucumber", "watercress":
    print("That would make a good tea sandwich.")
case let x where x.hasSuffix("pepper"):
    print("Is it a spicy \(x)?")
default:
    print("Everything tastes good in soup.")
}
```

The error am getting is `: error: value of type 'String' has no member 'hasSuffix'
    case let x where x.hasSuffix("pepper"):`

Am using `ubuntu 14.04` and my version of Swift is `swift --version
Swift version 3.0 (swift-3.0-PREVIEW-2)`

Comment: All I can say is that this is valid Swift 3.0 code (it works fine on my Xcode Playground). Why don't you try the [3.0.1 GM Candidate](https://swift.org/download/#previews) version?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `hasSuffix(_:)` member of `String` is bridged from `NSString` (and in so from Foundation). When working with Swift in Xcode Playgrounds and projects, this method is available from the Swift standard library, whereas when compiling Swift from e.g. the IBM sandbox/your local Linux machine, the Swift std-lib version is not accessible, whereas the one from core-libs Foundation is.

To have access to the latter implementation, you need to explicitly import Foundation:

```
import Foundation // <---

let vegetable = "red pepper"
switch vegetable {
case "celery":
    print("Add some raisins and make ants on a log.")
case "cucumber", "watercress":
    print("That would make a good tea sandwich.")
case let x where x.hasSuffix("pepper"):
    print("Is it a spicy \(x)?")
default:
    print("Everything tastes good in soup.")
}
```

Most Swift tutorials will assume execution via Xcode, and `import Foundation` can be good first attempted remedy for any *"... has no member ..."* errors when compiling Swift outside of Xcode.

---

#### Details

As @Hamish points out in a comment below (thanks!), one implementation of `hasSuffix(_:)` is available from the standard library, with the requirement of `_runtime(_ObjC)`, however.

From [swift/stdlib/public/core/StringLegacy.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/StringLegacy.swift):

> ```
> #if _runtime(_ObjC)
>
> // ...
>
> public func hasSuffix(_ suffix: String) -> Bool { 
>     // ...
> }
>
> #else
> // FIXME: Implement hasPrefix and hasSuffix without objc
> // rdar://problem/18878343
> #endif
> ```

Another implementation can be used in case the one above is not accessible (e.g. from Linux). Accessing this method requires an implicit `import Foundation` statement, however.

From [swift-corelibs-foundation/Foundation/NSString.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/4ae14fbbceb0c2f634edf4e66a1b3c19b80b94f5/Foundation/NSString.swift):

> ```
> #if !(os(OSX) || os(iOS))
> extension String {
>
>     // ...
>
>     public func hasSuffix(_ suffix: String) -> Bool {
>         // ... core foundation implementation
>     }
> }
> #endif
> ```

Comment: That's true for all Swift source files, not just on Linux.

Comment: @TimVermeulen You're right! I'm unsure, however, how we're given this for free e.g. when working with a single `.swift` file in an Xcode project (no need for explicitly importing Foundation). Also for Playground we needn't explicitly import Foundation for access to such bridged methods. Do you know how this "behind-the-hood" access to Foundation methods work in Xcode?

Comment: Seems like they didn't mentioned this in the tutorial may be because it is auto loaded in X code but not in Linux.

Comment: @dfri Confusingly enough, there actually appears to be two `hasSuffix(_:)` implementations for `String` – [one from the standard library](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/StringLegacy.swift#L201) (that requires `_runtime(_ObjC)`, which OP doesn't have) & [one from core-libs foundation](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/4ae14fbbceb0c2f634edf4e66a1b3c19b80b94f5/Foundation/NSString.swift#L1437), which OP *can* use. Therefore OP needs to `import Foundation`, but those of us with access to the Obj-C runtime don't :)

Comment: @Hamish ah, that explains that curiosity, nice digging! Thanks :)

Comment: @dfri I didn't try it, and just assumed the `import Foundation` was needed in a regular Xcode project as well! Oops.

Comment: Bloody hell, this took me ages to figure out. 

I'm looking into Swift on my Linux machine, ran into `error: type 'String' has no member 'Encoding'` and couldn't for the life of me figure out why some method on such a basic type was unavailable to me. 

You'd think they'd clearly and explicitly document something like this. Everybody seems to be using Xcode: I found exactly 0 examples, explanations and tutorials where they used `import Foundation`.